# Unity3d on Linux - which installer to choose?

Tags: ubuntu, debian

I want to try Unity on Debian. I found out that there is currently two installers: supported one for Ubuntu and another one (unsupported) for other Linux distributions.
It's confusing fact since Ubuntu is based on Debian. And Ubuntu uses the same package extension (.deb) as Debian does. So, the question is: will I get Ubuntu installer working well on my Debian or should I choose unsupported installer instead?

Comment: I'm not sure this is the correct place for this question. Maybe try asking on http://askubuntu.com/

Comment: @David sorry, my bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Ubuntu installer. As you wrote, Ubuntu is based on Debian and, because of this, some packages work and some not. You could try it.

Comment: Thank you. The Ubuntu version seems to work. I will try to run some basic project soon.